# Is for a convex, continuous function f satisfying $Cf(s)f(t) \leq f(st) \leq Df(s)f(t)$ for some constants C>0 and D>0, implies that $f(t)=t^p$?

Tags: functions, inequality

If $f(t)=t^p$, then f satisfies  $Df(s)f(t) \leq f(st) \leq Df(s)f(t)$ for all s,t>0, for some constants C=1>0 and D=1>0. Can we get any other example other than $t^p$.

Comment: 1. $Df(s)f(t) \leq f(st) \leq Df(s)f(t)$ or $\color{red}{C}f(s)f(t) \leq f(st) \leq Df(s)f(t)$ ? 2. Do you know other constants $C,D$ than both being $1$ ?

Comment: C and D are different constants. for example take  $C<1$ and $D>1$.